# Are there any theaters that are receptive to manuscripts for monologues from the author/performer?

Tags: screenwriting, playwriting

First, a caveat: I am only the author of the "play" in question in a sense of the word; since much of the monologue is drawn verbatim from the writings and speeches of Mark Twain, I am really just the co-author.

That having been said, the script is to a great extent "mine" - the order and connections from one anecdote to the next are unique to me.

Anyway, what I want to know is whether there are theaters that seek, or are at least receptive to, producing a play to be performed by the author (that is to say me, as my "collaborator" is unavailable)?

Something like [this](http://www.forwardtheater.com/learn/submissions), perhaps, but I am no longer a Wisconsin resident, so that won't work for me (I'm in Monterey, California).

Comment: Did you get anyone yet?  I.e. for a one–person play portraying Samuel Clemens?

Comment: I only gave one performance for pay; it’s been very slow

Comment: How was it received?  Good reviews?  You might want to consider posting your own answer with that information.

Comment: People liked it; these were verbal comments, though; I don't think the time is right, for whatever reason, for a Twain show right now. I gave it a go. Maybe I will again in the future, but I'm currently sensing more interest in school presentations on "Indians"; see https://www.amazon.com/Indians-U-S-Overview-Historical-Figures/dp/1976017645/

Comment: If you've created a work that includes verbatim quotes from what another person has said or written, you are not a co-author, you are either a licensee (if you have paid the owner of the copyrights to the original stories) or a copyright infringer (if you have not licensed the quotes). Mark Twain might be in the public domain, or he might not. It's not a given.

Comment: You know it has been done before, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Twain_Tonight!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you talk to someone who does historical monologues professionally. I've found that there is no substitute when entering into an endeavor for speaking with someone who has done it before.

I can recommend ["Barefoot" Bill Pacer](http://www.facebook.com/barefootbill) as someone who has done things very similar to what you propose.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a writer or actor or writer/actor is not going to enter a relationship directly with a theater. You really need to fill two other important jobs, at a bare minimum:

- Director
- Producer

You might be able to get away with being your own director, but the big danger is that you'll have no other voice looking at your writing and acting and helping you hone it and make it as good as it can be.

The fact that you have this question about getting into theaters means you do not have the knowledge to be a producer. You want to find a producer for your play and they will know how to get it onto a stage.